# Breeze: Cannot read property 'isAnonymous' of undefined

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, breeze

I am using Breeze and Entity Framework on a project I am leading for my company. My database is a little weird with the naming, but so far it hasn't been a problem. I'm trying to query a 'Calls' resource and check a bunch of properties to see if they contain a search value.

I'm getting this error when I run the query: `Cannot read property 'isAnonymous' of undefined`.

Here is the relevant code:

```
var predicate = new breeze.Predicate('Call_ID', '==', searchNum)
    .or('tbl_eJob_Info.Organization', 'contains', search)
    .or('tbl_eJob_Info.tbl_eCust_Contacts', 'any', 'First', 'contains', search);

var query = entityQuery.from('Calls').where(predicate);

...

return manager.executeQuery(query)
    .then(querySucceeded).fail(queryFailed);
```

The error is caused by the line `.or('tbl_eJob_Info.tbl_eCust_Contacts', 'any', 'First', 'contains', search);`

My research has turned up problems with resource names, foreign key constraints, and the like. I've tried adding Resource / Entity Type relationships to the metadata and all that jazz, but nothing has solved it so far. I've checked the metadata and the relationships that go down that chain are clearly established. I'm at a loss. Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if any more information is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much hair-pulling and confusion, I finally figured out that this:

```
metadata.setEntityTypeForResourceName('Calls', 'tbl_eCT_Call_Info');
```

is what I needed to do to fix it. I thought it was something wrong with the property, but it looks like it was just something wrong with the way Breeze was interpreting the resource and entity type.